# FlowRouter and email verification token

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

If I change the verify-email so it wouldn't have the # in it , My user is not getting verified , once they landed on the page i want them to , and keeps asking for email verification .shown in code below 
this is how i change the verify email link

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function(token){
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl("verify-email/" + token);
 };
```

and here is my router ( I am using FlowRouter not iron-router )

```
FlowRouter.route('/verify-email/:token',{
    name: 'verifyEmail',
    action: function(){
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {content: 'VerifyEmail'});
    }
});
```

and here is how I verify the user

```
Template.VerifyEmail.created = function() {
    if (Accounts._verifyEmailToken) {
        Accounts.verifyEmail(Accounts._verifyEmailToken, function(err) {
            if (err != null) {
                if (err.message = 'Verify email link expired [403]') {
                    console.log('Sorry this verification link has expired.')
                }
            } else {
                console.log('You account is active now !')
            }
        });
    }
 };
```

If I do not change the sent verify link and let the original verification token sent , once its clicked it goes to the home page of and i need to change the Template.VerifyEmail.created = function() to 
Template.Home.created = function() it works which is not what i want
thanks

Comment: Won't resolve your issue, but you're using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator:  `if (err.message = 'Verify email...)` should be `if (err.message === 'Verify email...)`